# Work of friction along a circular path using dot product

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, work, friction

Good day guys, I was working on circular motion and was wondering about the following:

I have seen that the work done by friction along a circular path is given by
$$W = F_fS$$
I was wondering if it was possible to derive this relationship using the dot product, such that:
$$W = \vec{F_f}\cdot \vec{\Delta s} = F_f S$$

I have tried setting up $\vec{\Delta s} = <Rcos\theta,Rsin\theta>$. However I have been unable to derive the relationship.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yipee, Here we go, As a nice recall, force due to friction always acts in the opposing direction to motion.

So as we move around the circle, the force of friction will act in the opposite direction to $e_{\theta}$, which is a vector that is tangential to our circle. We can express $e_{\theta}$ as following: $e_{\theta} = (-sin(\theta),cos(\theta))$

Hence $$\vec{F_f} = F_f(-e_\theta)$$

Assuming constant friction along the circular path we can derive the desired equation:

$$\int_{Circle}\vec{F_f}\cdot d\vec{s}  = \int_{0}^{2\pi}F_f(-e_\theta)\cdot \frac{d\vec{s}}{d\theta}d\theta$$

You had the correct parameterisation for $s$, $s=(Rcos(\theta),Rsin(\theta))$

$$\implies \frac{d\vec{s}}{d\theta} = (-Rsin(\theta),Rcos(\theta)) = Re_{\theta}$$

Thus:

$$\int_{Circle}\vec{F_f}\cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{0}^{2\pi}-RF_f(e_{\theta}\cdot e_{\theta})d\theta = -RF_f[\theta]_{0}^{2\pi}=-F_f(2\pi R) = -F_fS$$

This is the expression for the work done against friction which implies work done by friction:

$$W = F_fS$$

Hope this helps :).

Sorry I should add given more context:

The formula $W = F \cdot \Delta $ is a specific case formula. More generally:

$W = \int_C F \cdot ds$, which is called a line integral. Physics runs deeP into that calculus.